# Using WebApplicationBuilder in an extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am posting this question to find out whether I am using the WebApplicationBuilder in the right way. I am registering my project dependencies by using an extension method as below. I am using the WebApplicationBuilder directly as I can access IServiceCollection and ConfigurationManager instances from the builder and avoid passing multiple parameters to my extension.

```
public static class MessageBrokerServiceExtensions
{
    public static void AddMessageBrokerClient(
        this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var messageBrokerOptions = builder.Configuration
            .GetSection(MessageBrokerOptions.Position);

        builder.Services
            .AddOptions<MessageBrokerOptions>()
            .Bind(messageBrokerOptions)
            .ValidateDataAnnotations()
            .ValidateOnStart();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMessageBrokerContext, MessageBrokerContext>();
        //register other dependencies
    }
}
```

In my Program.cs, I have

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.AddMessageBrokerClient();
...
var app = builder.Build();
await app.RunAsync();
```

This works well. But, how can I test my extension? I do it as below:

```
    [Fact]
    public void RegistersDependenciesCorrectly_WithConfiguredClient()
    {
        // Arrange
        var configDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "MessageBroker:Name", "RabbitMq" },
            { "MessageBroker:ConnectionString", "dummy-connection" },
            { "MessageBroker:QueueName", "sample-queue" }
        };
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        builder.Configuration.AddInMemoryCollection(configDictionary);

        // Act
        builder.AddMessageBrokerClient();
        using var app = builder.Build();
        
        // Assert
        var messageBrokerContextService =
            app.Services.GetRequiredService<IMessageBrokerContext>();
        var messageBrokerOptions = app.Services
            .GetRequiredService<IOptions<MessageBrokerOptions>>().Value;

        messageBrokerOptions.Name.Should().Be(MessageBrokerEnum.RabbitMq);
        messageBrokerOptions.ConnectionString.Should().Be("dummy-connection");
        messageBrokerContextService.Should().BeOfType<MessageBrokerContext>();
        messageBrokerContextService.MessageBrokerClient
            .Should().BeOfType<RabbitMqClient>();
    }
```

The concern I have with this approach is not disposing the WebApplicationBuilder. Can I make this any better with [WebApplicationFactory as fixture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-webapplicationfactory)? Any other suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Note: To use WebApplicationBuilder, I had to use the following framework reference:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 6 `WebApplicationBuilder` does not implement `IDisposable`. Why do you need to dispose of it?

Comment: Yes, it does not. The ```WebApplication``` does. What I really meant to ask is whether it is OK to use the ```WebApplicationBuilder``` this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would best to stick with using the IServicesCollection, so you are binding your worker class to interface rather than a class.
The call to the Service registration method would be

```
AddMessageBrokerClient(this IServiceCollection services)
```

Then your call in Program.cs would be

```
builder.Services.AddMessageBrokerClient();
```

This would mean you could mock the IServiceCollection and IConfiguration

But that is just how I would do it.